# How to show aggregated values in a CARTO BUILDER popup?

Tags: carto, popup

Is it possible to have some column calculations displayed in popups?

Given this example map:

https://atomotic.carto.com/builder/8238cb36-0f15-4fa4-9c80-cdce7c2bd040/embed

I would like to:

- display a popup on a city that shows a value calculated using `sum` on a
  column,
- access the value selected on category widget in order to
  compose an URL.

Comment: I don't really understand your second question. Please elaborate.

Comment: suppose i select the category *Iuristarum* from the Universitas widget: then i want to design a pop-up (using html editor) showing a link, for example https://my-site/universitas/iuristarum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a [Find centroid analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/find-centroid-of-geometries) to your layer. Grouping them by your `city` column and getting the `sum` aggregated value of your `numero` field. Then go to the POP-UP options and select `category` and `value` from the list of fields.